# Replace the column value with a particular string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this Dataframe: I want to replace the 1 with df.rule1 and 2 with df.rule2

```
+---+---------+------+
|SNo|Operation|Points|
+---+---------+------+
|  1|    1 & 2|   100|
|  2|    1 | 2|   200|
|  3|1 | 2 & 3|   350|
+---+---------+------+
```

I want this dataframe into this:

```
+---+------------------------------+------+
|SNo|Operation                     |Points|
+---+------------------------------+------+
|1  |df.rule1 & df.rule2           |100   |
|2  |df.rule1 | df.rule2           |200   |
|3  |df.rule1 | df.rule2 & df.rule3|350   |
+---+------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: is it pandas or spark dataframe ?

Comment: spark dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that is a `pyspark` `DataFrame`, we can use `regexp_replace`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('Operation', F.regexp_replace('Operation', r'\d', r'df.rule\1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.replace` with `regex=True`:

```
df['Operation'].replace('(\d)', 'df.rule\\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0               df.rule1 & df.rule2
1               df.rule1 | df.rule2
2    df.rule1 | df.rule2 & df.rule3
Name: Operation, dtype: object
```